# Vue-Slick and v-for with dynamic data

Tags: vue.js

i'm using vue-slick to show my images..
i've tried every solution that i found.. but none is working.

here is my template:

```
<slick ref="slick" :options="slickOptions">
 <img v-for="(item) in categories"  :src="'/images/category/'+item.image_url" alt="" class="img-fluid" >
</slick>
```

and here is my scripts:

```
 data () {
        return {
            categories:'',
            slickOptions: {
                dots: true,
                infinite: false,
                autoplay: false,
                arrows : false,                    
                draggable:true,
                speed: 1000,
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
            },
        }
    },
     mounted() {
        let _this = this;
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/api/category',
            data : {'name' : _this.name}
        }).then( (response)=> {
            console.log(response.data.data);
            _this.categories = response.data.data;
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error.response)
        });
    },
    methods:{
        next() {
            this.$refs.slick.next();
        },

        prev() {
            this.$refs.slick.prev();
        },
        reInit() {                
            this.$refs.slick.reSlick()
        }
    },
```

and only loading the image, and the slick is not working...!!?

Answer (score 4):

I have faced the same issue, and what I did to solve this is to put the

`v-if="categories.length > 0"` on the `<slick>` tag.

It make the slick won't be created before the data that we want to display contains the data first.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your Axios is returning data with the structure you are looking for.

I'm also assuming you are using the vue-slick component and not slick.

You should iterate through a DIV like stated in the documentation. Without Axios, I did this:

**In template**:

```
<slick ref="slick" :options="slickOptions">
      <div>Escolhe uma configuração...</div>
      <div v-for="d in data1"><a class="inline" :href="d.image"><img :src="d.image" alt="">{{ d.text }}</a></div>       
</slick>
```

**In Javascript**:

```
data: function() {
    return {
        data1: [
          {  image: 'http://placehold.it/100x100', text: 'Config1' }, 
          {  image: 'http://placehold.it/100x100', text: 'Config2' }, 
          {  image: 'http://placehold.it/100x100', text: 'Config3' }, 
          {  image: 'http://placehold.it/100x100', text: 'Config4' } 
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

*Use below code to reinit slick, and call on success function of response*

```
 reInit() {

    let currIndex = this.$refs.slick.currentSlide()
    this.$refs.slick.destroy()
    this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.$refs.slick.create()
        this.$refs.slick.goTo(currIndex, true)
    })
 }
```